# Vue updating user and prefilling form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I have problem with my Vue app. I create a user, then I want to update him, I open update form but fields are empty. My v-model is: username. When i change v-model to: bozpUsers.username, I have prefilled that field with actual username, but when I send it to db a refresh, everything is empty.

My code is here:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="orange lighten-2 white--text">Upraviť používateľa: {{ bozpUsers.username }}</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-text-field color="orange lighten-2 white--text"
              label="Používateľské meno"
              required
              v-model="username"
              append-icon="mdi-account"
              clearable
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-text-field color="orange lighten-2 white--text"
              label="Heslo"
              type="password"
              required
              v-model="password"
              append-icon="mdi-lock"
              clearable
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="orange lighten-2 white--text" @click="$emit('close-card')">
        Zavrieť
          <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        color="orange lighten-2 white--text"
        @click="updateUser"
      >
        Uložiť
        <v-icon>mdi-content-save</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
import UsersService from '@/services/UsersService';

export default {
  props: ["bozpUsers"],
  data: () => ({
    id: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
    role: "user",
    error: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    async updateUser() {
      this.error = null;
      const bozpUpdatedUser = {
        id: this.id,
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        role: this.role,
      }
      UsersService.put(this.bozpUsers.id, bozpUpdatedUser).then((response) => {
        this.$emit("close-card");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.error = "Failed to submit data - please try again later.";
        });
    },
  },
};

</script>
```

Is there any solution to this?
Can I have prefilled fields and when I send that data to db, they will actually save?

Comment: you can use bozpUsers.username as your model and have you tried to prevent your click so refresh wont happen and your data will be still displayed ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but in database I have empty strings then. I fixed it, I change inside method: 
        username: this.bozpUser.username,
        password: this.bozpUser.password,